# vtree object is renderred in Rmarkdown but not in quarto

Tags: r, r-markdown, htmlwidgets, quarto, vtree

**I use updated `quarto` and `Rmarkdown` and  `vtree ‘5.4.6’`:**

***In the same project and same session:***

`Rmarkdown` does what `quarto` does not:
`Rmarkdown` renders `vtree(iris, "Species")` and `quarto` not (allthough `quarto` renders inline)

**What could be the problem for this?**

**See here a reproducible example:**

## 1. Rmarkdown

````
---
title: "test"
author: "Me"
date: '2022-06-18'
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
library(vtree)
```

## R Markdown

```{r cars}
vtree(iris, "Species")
```
````

[image]

## 2. Quarto

````
---
title: "Untitled"
format: html
editor: visual
---

## Quarto

```{r}
library(vtree)
vtree(iris, "Species")
```
````

**When I click the Render button: -> it is NOT renderred:**
[image]

**When I render inline: -> it is renderred:**
[image]

Comment: Not able to reproduce your error though (tested on Mac)

Comment: Hmmhh. I will shut down everything and restart.

Comment: I was using the same version for vtree.  It may be an issue in your env as it relates to the path

Comment: I used `packageVersion('knitr')#
[1] ‘1.39’`  If it is not working, can you change `options(knitr.graphics.rel_path = TRUE)`

Comment: Now it says `Watching files for changes
  /xxxx/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpkvBd5n/vtree001.png (404: Not Found)`

Comment: Not sure as you are using windows

Comment: Many thanks Master anyway. It is like a black whole sometimes. I think I do something fundamental wrong. And I think it has to do with loading the data from extern device (database, USB stick), wrangling data, doing the analysis. That said, allthough all is in the global environment, when rendering there must be lack of access to the created dataframe. But never mind. I am sure I will solve this also. Still learning! Many thanks again for caring. You are definitely one of the shining lights of R programming commuinty for me!

Comment: I believe this is an issue with vtree directly which does not support how Quarto is working. vtree function will write to file in a R session temp folder, which is persistent only for a R session. so it assumes that the knitting process happens in the same session as when the file is needed. With quarto, the conversion to HTML does not happen in R and the file saved have been removed when the R session used for knitting is closed. So I think this is a vtree package issue which does not write in the right place. I would open an issue there - you can tag me there if needed.

Comment: @cderv. Thank you very much for taking time and explaining. This is so helpful!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quarto works a bit differently than R Markdown as it will run R only for the knitting process, and not for the conversion to output format, here HTML.

From the error message, **vtree** is writing to file the output in the R session temp folder. This folder is not persistent after the R session is closed, which happens once Quarto have run all the computation output. This means that the `png` file does not exists anymore when converting to HTML, hence the no image shown in HTML.

(regarding knitr warning, I believe it is knitr version matter, but that does not change the output).

Looking at `vtree::vtree()` function, it seems when knitting to HTML is detected R temp folder is used if none provided. IMO this should ne behave that way and it is an issue in **vtree** package.

To overcome the issue, you need to not let **vtree** do the default provide yourself a path. You can do that with `folder` argument. So this should work

````markdown
---
title: "Untitled"
format: html
keep-md: true
---

## Quarto

```{r}
library(vtree)
if (!dir.exists("vtree_save")) dir.create("vtree_save")
vtree(iris, "Species", folder = "vtree_save")
```
````

I would report an issue in **vtree** repo about this behavior.

Comment: Unbelievable. I was thinking about days for this problem. Outstanding! Will you open an issue?

Comment: You can do it @TarJae if you don't mind as you found the issue as a user. You can ping me there using `@cderv`

Comment: I opened the issue: <https://github.com/nbarrowman/vtree/issues/31>

Answer (score 1):

I am the author of the vtree package. I have just made a change to the code which I believe fixes the problem. See https://github.com/nbarrowman/vtree where there are instructions for downloading version 5.5.8 of the vtree package, which includes the fix.